# Modify HTML file to embed all external Scripts and CSS into <script> and <style> tags

Tags: javascript, python, html, build, embed

I am searching for a way to automatically put all my scripts into the script tag in my HTML file.

So I want this:

```
<script src="..."></script>
<script src="..."></script> 
...
```

To be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    all the JavaScript code from every Script file
    ...
</script>
```

Could this be done with ant or a bat or something else?

I also want the JavaScript to be minified. But thats not the point.

Thanks in advance.

**MORE INFOS:**

So what I already have is an bat file that minifies all JavaScript files and all CSS files into one *main.js* and *main.css*:

```
index.html
main.js
main.css
```

But I only want a **single *index.html*** file containing all CSS and JavaScript. So I can offer this single file as an offline Webapp.

So basically I need a way to build this *index.html* file by:

- removing external Scripts Links
- removing external CSS Links
- add the compressed JavaScript into script tag
- add the compressed CSS into style tag

Comment: GruntJS and GulpJS are popular tools for building front end resources. Is it a requirement to use ant or bat?

Comment: I personally would recommend python for this. Regular expression would cut down your work load.

Comment: Thanks. No there are no requirements at all. See my changes above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as Monacraft recommend I´ve used Python (first time) to modify/create the html file.

Now I only have to run this:

```
python build.py ../source.html target.html
```

See the code above:

```py
import sys, re, os
from collections import deque
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
from jsmin import jsmin
from csscompressor import compress

# html param 
html = sys.argv[1]
# target param 
target = sys.argv[2]
# path from html param
path = re.sub(r"[^\/]*$", "", html)
# open html file
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html))
# find last script as anchorpoint
lastScript = soup.findAll("script", attrs = {"src" : True})[-1]
# get all scripts containing src attribute (= external scripts)
scripts = soup.findAll("script", attrs = {"src" : True})
# find last style link as anchorpoint
lastStylesheet = soup.findAll("link", attrs = {"rel" : "stylesheet"})[-1]
# get all links to css stylesheets
stylesheets = soup.findAll("link", attrs = {"rel" : "stylesheet"})

# create list of script srcs
print("\nRead Scripts:")
scriptsSrc = deque()
for script in scripts:
    scriptsSrc.append(path + script.attrs["src"])
    print("\t" + path + script.attrs["src"])

# create list of stylesheets srcs
print("\nRead Stylesheets:")
stylesheetsSrc = deque()
for stylesheet in stylesheets:
    stylesheetsSrc.append(path + stylesheet.attrs["href"])
    print("\t" + path + stylesheet.attrs["href"])

# merge scripts to temp.js
print("\nMerge Scripts:")
print("\t", end="")
with open("temp.js", "w") as outfileScript:
    for fname in scriptsSrc:
        # add space every script
        outfileScript.write("\n")
        print("~", end="")
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfileScript.write(line)
print("\n");

# merge stylsheets to temp.css
print("Merge Stylesheets:")
print("\t", end="")
with open("temp.css", "w") as outfileCSS:
    for fname in stylesheetsSrc:
        # add space every script
        outfileCSS.write("\n")
        print("~", end="")
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfileCSS.write(line)
print("\n");

# minify javascript
print("Minify temp.js\n\t~")
with open("temp.js") as js:
    minified_js = jsmin(js.read())

# minify css
print("\nMinify temp.css\n\t~")
with open("temp.css") as css:
    minified_css = compress(css.read())

# replace scripts with merged and min embed script / css
print("\nReplacing and deleting\n\t~")
tag = soup.new_tag("script")
tag["type"] = "text/javascript"
tag.append(minified_js)
lastScript.replace_with(tag)

tag = soup.new_tag("style")
tag["type"] = "text/css"
tag.append(minified_css)
lastStylesheet.replace_with(tag)

#remove script and style tags
for script in scripts:
    script.decompose()
for stylesheet in stylesheets:
    stylesheet.decompose()

#remove temp
os.remove("temp.js")
os.remove("temp.css")

#save html as target
file = open(target,"w")
file.write(soup.prettify())
file.close()

print("\nFIN\n")
```

How it works:

- Load source HTML
- Search for <script> with "src"-attribute and <link> with "rel"-attribute
- Merge scripts and css in temp files
- Minify them
- Embed them into the html file (where the last tag of script/link was found)
- Remove <script> (src) and <link> (rel) tags
- Save as target HTML

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use on linux, a simple shell script to do the work.
It just merge all the files in one.
https://github.com/dfsq/compressJS.sh

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my question. I know how to merge the files. The question is how to add the merged JS and CSS directly into the HTML file?!